# jQuery-UI Accordion control with button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to control my jQuery UI Accordian with the click of a button.  However, when I click the button, nothing happens.

Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks

Here's a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/VLBw5/

Here is my javascript:

```
    $('[name=myButton]').on('click' , function() {
        $("#textSection").accordion({
            event: 'click',
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="textSection">
     This is a course about biology.
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" name="myButton" value="Toggle" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this 3 line inside the HEAD tag.

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```